# Next.js client side and server side bootstrapping code

Tags: bootstrapping, next.js

Where can I put code which will be bootstrapped in both the server side as well as the client side? I need some logic in both ends and do not want to be bothered maintaining this in multiple places. I tried / considered:

- adding it to `src/components/_app.js` in the `constructor` but this seems only to be executed on the client-side (or not early enough for `getInitialsProps` on server side).
- adding it to both `_app.js` `constructor` and `server.js`, though that means that my logic cannot be using the module system `import` because `server.js` is not compiled like that.

Comment: Could you please provide basic expected example as a simplified repo? As I did it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476842/importerror-no-module-named-google-cloud-error-reporting/55481717

Answer (score 0):

It will help to give some context to it. When you say code that will be bootstrapped, do you mean a function that will be executed, or are you looking for a common codebase, for example a utility function that is used both in client side and in server side.

I'm assuming you mean having a file that will be executed both on the client side and on the server side (the case of the utility function). With that, you could consider putting the file in the root of the project, that way, e.g. `./util.js`

This means that if you need it in the client side (e.g. `./pages/index.js`) you could reference it like so:

```
 import { testUtil } from '../util.js';
```

And if you need it in the server folder (I prefer having my server code inside a `./server` directory), you reference it like so:

```
const { testUtil } = require('../util.js');
```

The only downside is that you have to write the code not using the ES6 constructs to ensure interoperability between both the client and the server.