# ImportError: No module named google.cloud.error_reporting

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-app-engine-python, pipenv

A few weeks ago I've installed Ubuntu 18.10 at home and today I decided to move from Windows to this OS at home.

I use it for Python development.

Unfortunately, I faced with some strange error and don't know how to solve it.

When I try to run my project I see next error during simple request

```
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1154, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.error_reporting
```

When I run pip show `google_cloud_error_reporting` it shows me proper info about the package

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Name: google-cloud-error-reporting
Version: 0.30.1
Summary: Stackdriver Error Reporting API client library
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google LLC
Author-email: googleapis-packages@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/p35/.local/share/virtualenvs/tt-T7X9xdJU/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: google-cloud-logging
Required-by:
```

Output from `gcloud --version`

```
Google Cloud SDK 240.0.0
alpha 2019.03.22
app-engine-python 1.9.84
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.84
beta 2019.03.22
bq 2.0.42
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2019.03.22
gsutil 4.37
kubectl 2019.03.22
```

I tried to reinstall **pipenv**, **setuptools**, project dependencies itself, but nothing helps me.

Simplified project https://github.com/pahan35/google-cloud-error-reporting-import-bug

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this problem: we should add google dependencies via `vendor.add([any_accessible_folder])` and then either run a project under another interpreter or we need to remove all google dependencies from the current pipenv interpreter.

## Workaround (right solution still welcome)

For this specific project I did next steps.

Common steps

1. Install all pipenv dependencies to `lib` folder via command

   `pipenv run pip install -r <(pipenv lock -r) -t lib --upgrade`
2. Use your local folder as another source of packages in your entry file before imported google cloud dependency

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')

from google.cloud import error_reporting # causing problems dependency
```

3. Then you need either remove google packages from your pipenv interpreter **or** use another one. I tested both: B is easier but may cause unexpected conflicts or missed packages

### A. Clear current pipenv interpreter from all google cloud dependencies

1. Enter into pipenv shell via command `pipenv shell`
2. See installed packages via `pip list`
3. Remove all google cloud packages plus some extra noticed via iterated runs

   ```
   pip uninstall google_cloud_error_reporting google_auth google_core google_cloud_core google_api_core google_cloud_logging googleapis_common_protos protobuf
   ```

   Maybe we can optimize it via removing all packages from pipenv interpreter?

### B. Use another interpreter

1. Find absolute path to desirable interpreter. I used a global one `/usr/bin/python`
2. Run the project via this interpreter like `/usr/bin/python $(which dev_appserver.py) .`

## Project

[Example project](https://github.com/pahan35/google-cloud-error-reporting-import-bug) contains applied workaround